# How to remove search button soft keyboard in android?

Tags: android, search, button, android-softkeyboard

I want to remove the search button from soft keyboard shown in the below image, how to do it? [image]

Comment: Did you want to replace it with "Go" or "Enter" or something like that or just remove it all together? I don't think it's possible to remove it, however I believe you can change it to "Go", "Enter", etc.

Comment: I just want to remove it or else don't perform any action on click on it.

Comment: try adding a `android:imeOptions` to the search bar in XML

Comment: which value i can give in it.It is not expecting Boolean

Comment: @BaZinga, Just please tell me how to perform our own action by clicking   on that search button.

Comment: you have that already . use android:imeOptions

Comment: Yes i have it,when i click on it it just refreshing that activity but i want to write my own action when i click on it, How?

Answer (score 2):

After searching a lot `android:imeOptions="actionNone"`. add this in your SearchView xml code.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                        android:id="@+id/searchView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNone"
                        android:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
                        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                        app:queryHint="Search Name" />
```

It replaces with next Line icon, you should try this first. Thanks, me latter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May it work but currently I don't have access to that code as it is a very old question.

Comment: your welcome, maybe its old question but I reached this year :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Bill Gary suggested, you can also call `setImeOptions()` on the `SearchView` object.